# How to convert this EF Cloning Code to use DBContext instead of EntityObject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I need to clone Master and Child Entities. I have come across this solution on CodeProject which seems to do the job, see: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/474296/Clone-an-Entity-in-Entity-Framework-4.

However I am using EF5 and DBContext whereas this code is using EF4 and EntityObject, so I am wondering what changes I need to make to it?

The code is:

```
public static T CopyEntity<T>(MyContext ctx, T entity, bool copyKeys = false) where T : EntityObject
{
T clone = ctx.CreateObject<T>();
PropertyInfo[] pis = entity.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pis)
{
    EdmScalarPropertyAttribute[] attrs = (EdmScalarPropertyAttribute[])
                  pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EdmScalarPropertyAttribute), false);

    foreach (EdmScalarPropertyAttribute attr in attrs)
    {
        if (!copyKeys && attr.EntityKeyProperty)
            continue;

        pi.SetValue(clone, pi.GetValue(entity, null), null);
    }
}

return clone;
```

}

The calling code is:

```
Customer newCustomer = CopyEntity(myObjectContext, myCustomer, false);

foreach(Order order in myCustomer.Orders)
{
Order newOrder = CopyEntity(myObjectContext, order, true);
newCustomer.Orders.Add(newOrder);
}
```

I am posting here as the feedbacks on this post look inactive and I am sure this is a question that could be answered by any EF pro.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a clone of an entity using EF5 `DbContext` the simplest way is this:

```
//clone of the current entity values
Object currentValClone = context.Entry(entityToClone)
                                .CurrentValues.ToObject();

//clone of the original entity values
Object originalValueClone = context.Entry(entityToClone)
                                    .OriginalValues.ToObject();

//clone of the current entity database values (results in db hit
Object dbValueClone = context.Entry(entityToClone)
                                   .GetDatabaseValues().ToObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will be work only if in your entity property has `EdmScalarPropertyAttribute`

alternatively you can use `MetadataWorkspace` to get entity property

```
public static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static TEntity CopyEntity<TEntity>(DbContext context, TEntity entity, bool copyKeys = false)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        ObjectContext ctx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        TEntity clone = null;
        if (ctx != null)
        {
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            try
            {
                clone = ctx.CreateObject<TEntity>();
                var objectEntityType = ctx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.OSpace).Where(x => x.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType).OfType<EntityType>().Where(x => x.Name == clone.GetType().Name).Single();

                var pis = entity.GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t.CanWrite);
                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pis)
                {
                    var key = objectEntityType.KeyProperties.Where(t => t.Name == pi.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (key != null && !copyKeys)
                        continue;
                    pi.SetValue(clone, pi.GetValue(entity, null), null);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
            }
        }
        return clone;
    }
}
```